# Old website is seen when new version of angular2 app is published

Tags: angular, caching

Whenever any changes are deployed in the angular 2 application, the old version of the application is seen. This is resolved when cache is cleaned. How to solve this without clearing cache, since we cannot tell the clients to clear cache before using the application.

Comment: Can you show the content of your `index.html` file in the question?

Comment: How are you building/deploying your application, and what version of Angular are you using? If you are in fact using Angular 2.x I would invest some time updating to the latest versions of Angular. The newer versions of the CLI have `output-hashing` enabled by default when using `ng build --prod` - essentially meaning cache-busting is always active if you build using the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar situation and fixed it with following two approaches:

1. Use Angular AOT Build with hashing enabled, if you havent yet: 
   `ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing`
2. Another method that worked for us in addition to this was to set `antiResourceLocking` and `cachingAllowed` to `false` in `context.xml` of Tomcat server, where our app is deployed (if this applies to your situation). You can find more info on that [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).